# data on sidebar does not appear

Tags: javascript, webix

I was trying to develop webix header and sidebar by using html which I have seen below. Currently it is developed in javascript.

http://docs.webix.com/samples/28_sidemenu/01_sidebar.html

I am changing from javascript to html

Header,icons,sidebar eveything appearing in the html, however the contents on the sidebar does not appear. I am not sure whats the mistake I have done. Below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./codebase/webix.css" type="text/css"
    media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./codebase/sidebar.css" type="text/css"
    media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<script src="./codebase/webix.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="./codebase/sidebar.js" type="text/javascript"
    charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="./codebase/data.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        webix.ready(function() {
            webix.markup.init();
        });

        function toggle(){
            $$("$sidebar1").toggle()
        }

    </script>

    <div class="container" id="mainDiv"></div>

    <div data-view="rows">

        <div data-view="toolbar" data-padding="5">

            <div data-view="button" data-type="icon" data-icon="bars"
                data-width="37" data-align="left" data-css="app_button"
                data-click="toggle()"></div>
            <div data-view="label" data-label="My App"></div>

            <div data-view="button" data-type="icon" data-icon="envelope-o"
                data-width="45" data-css="app_button" data-badge="4"></div>
            <div data-view="button" data-type="icon" data-icon="bell-o"
                data-width="45" data-css="app_button" data-badge="10"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-view="cols">
        <div data-view="sidebar" data-id="sidebar" data-data="menu_data"></div> 

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused too, but parsing works correctly, i.e. $$("sidebar").parse(menu_data)

Comment: The component can't read data from variable name, so data-data="menu_data" will not work.You can use data-url and external files, or sidebar.parse to load data without an ajax call.  http://webix.com/snippet/68e4d1d1

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried by adding data-url="data.json", still I am unable to load the data. I used data-url="data.json". Still the same thing. I am getting the emply sidebar. I am not getting any error as well. One more thing I would like to point out that this is the same thing happens to list as well. When I add data-url="data.json" it does not get rendered.